# python colab notebook not printing?

Tags: python, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I'm following this paper: [Deep Image Prior](https://dmitryulyanov.github.io/deep_image_prior)

And on the code, I wanted to see log results but for some reason I don't see any of the prints.
For example on this notebook: [Super Resolution](https://colab.research.google.com/github/DmitryUlyanov/deep-image-prior/blob/master/super-resolution.ipynb) on the cells: Load image and baselines, and Define closure and optimize, there are print calls but I don't see anything printed when I run it.

Can someome please clarify?
Thanks!

Comment: I just run the notebook and I can watch the prints and the images (there are someones about zebras xD)

Comment: can't see the prints of this line:
print ('Iteration %05d    PSNR_LR %.3f   PSNR_HR %.3f' % (i, psnr_LR, psnr_HR), '\r', end='')

Answer (score 0):

I actually just had this issue. Try clicking this dropdown to the right of widget that shows how your program is using resources:
[A small widget showing resource usage next to the Colab AI button in the top right with the dropdown in between](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvr2b.png)
It's in the top right of your window and has a dropdown to its right. In the dropdown, navigate to Manage Sessions and click the trash can on the session you're having trouble with. Now, reload that session and it should work